# Is there an easy way to incorporate a site-wide login?

Tags: php, mysql, single-sign-on, mediawiki-extensions

I have a website that has a wiki and a forum that you can log into. I would like to be able to have a single site-wide user system, so I don't have to have separate users for both. If it helps, I am using MediaWiki 1.16.4 for my wiki, phpBB 3.0.8 for the forum, PHP version 5.3.5 and MySQL version 5.1.54.

Comment: If it's not out there already, you'll need to create custom code that bridges the two products. You should be able to do most of this through a custom login/registration script.

Comment: You mean Single Sign On (SSO)?  There's a few to choose from: Federated (Shibboleth, OpenID -- which you used to login here), CAS, Active Directory/LDAP...

Comment: I think there are some things out there for both of these to use OpenID already somewhere. Could be useful.

Comment: There's plenty of options. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Authentication_and_Authorization_Extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into rolling or integrating with a separate "single-sign-on service" which would provide some kind of immutable token which both the wiki and the forum could use. (This idea is sometimes called a "federated" identity -- various end user services can share a common authentication platform, and so provide seamless user experience, or nearly.)

Update: I see now your question is actually a little more subtle, and is asking after a straightforward way to share a user across multiple already existing applications. As far as I know this would not be trivial. I might consider looking at solutions that already offer a lot of the features you are after in a single package, or of course writing your own. I might also mention that it's not really that much to ask to have users remember different passwords for different applications, at least in certain situations. I might ask what is going on with this requirement, and am now wondering whether I have misunderstood, as it does seem kind of strange to ask to link together the user databases of a bunch of different applications, which may have vastly differing authentication schemes.

(I think what I'm saying is that, as far as I know, it would not be simple to setup a federated identity scheme for a bunch of applications that don't already support it. If those applications provide extensibility you may find or be able to write a plug-in that talks to an authentication provider.)

Comment: Well, I just have a website with 1 wiki and 1 forum, which I may or may not add to later. I want to let users have one username/password for the entire site, and have that work automatically (If a user registers for the forum, they are automatically registered for the wiki, and vice versa).

Comment: Well, there's a few possibilities. Either the wiki and forum support federation out the box, or you'll have to find plugins, or you'll have to write the bridge yourself. None of these, except perhaps the first, will be trivial. (Basically you'll want to weigh how badly you want shared authentication against the cost of implementing it.)

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember, phpBB's authentication is abstract and you can write your own layer.

Go from http://wiki.phpbb.com/Authentication_plugins for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Um, cookies? (set in the same domain, of course)

Comment: Ok, I'm kind of new to web programming in general, but I don't think cookies will work... I need to set up a way that any user created in the wiki is automatically added to the forum and vice versa, as well as being able to log in to both at once.

Comment: @cheeseisedible: Well why not? Picture this: user account created and cookie sent back to user. Contains server nonce/secret key along with username password, all encrypted. User goes to forum and cookie is sent along with log in request. Server decrypts it with it's secret key and finds the encrypted username and password. Do this over SSL and you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

Doing an include of some PhpBB files allows you to have a single sign on and use its authentication in other pages of the site, outside the forum. I did it in http://www.shertonenglish.com/. But, it's not an easy job and, I don't know  how easy could be altering the wiki script.

Here is a tutorial for PhpBB integration:
http://www.startrekguide.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=4576&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&hilit=integrate